# CURL, нужна помощь с запросом с использованием proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Есть такой сайт, который грузится только с использованием впн: https://www.yad2.co.il/

Мое задание - спарсить некоторые данные. Это я могу и умею, но проблема в том, что я не могу вытянуть хтмл-ку. Нашла сайт со списком прокси серверов, пробовала такое:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.yad2.co.il/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '110.232.252.249:8080');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Rigor/1.0.0; http://rigor.com)']);
```

И такое:

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.yad2.co.il/');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '110.232.252.249:8080');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 8080);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Rigor/1.0.0; http://rigor.com)']);
```

И много других разных комбинаций, но ничего не выходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как достать содержимое сайта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозрительный сайт. Чего это Вы там делаете а? )))

```
$url = "https://www.yad2.co.il/";
function get_url($url) {
    $proxy_ip = '157.245.124.217:3128';

    $ch = curl_init();

    if($ch === false)
    {
        die('Failed to create curl object');
    }

    $timeout = 25;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip );

    //доступные значения для типа используемого прокси-сервера:  CURLPROXY_HTTP (по умолчанию), CURLPROXY_SOCKS4, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5, CURLPROXY_SOCKS4A или CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Rigor/1.0.0; http://rigor.com)']);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

echo get_url($url);
```

Comment: Это фриланс, там большинство задач разные) спасибо за ответ, сейчас проверю

Comment: У меня зависает на "loading site please wait". У вас тоже, или сайт все таки прогрузился?

Comment: @Bipa запустите через консоль. Всё увидите )

Comment: Ухты, спасибо огромное. И это выйдет спарсить phpQuery или DOMDocument?

Comment: @Bipa, да, почему нет )

Comment: Я недосмотрела, через консоль тоже возвращает "loading site" :c

Comment: @Bipa, Вы уверены? У меня данные прогрузились. Какой-то сайт колл-центра.

Comment: @Bipa там есть ещё такая инфо на этом сайте - Сайт использует службу безопасности для предотвращения онлайн-атак. <br> Для просмотра сайта необходима полная поддержка скриптов. <br> Пожалуйста, включите опцию java script в браузере и попробуйте снова. Может у Вас отключен?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103548/discussion-between-bipa-and-denis640kb).